# 2 NIC's are not loading by the Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nic, gigabit-ethernet

I have a Server with 5 NIC's.

And I have just installed Ubuntu Server 11.10 64 bit fully dist-upgraded by now (31 Jan)

3 NIC's are identical PCI-Express x4 adapters.
1 is integrated TG3
and the last one is PCI but with the same RealTek chipset as those 3 NIC's (r8169)

My system is only seeing three NICs and assigning their `eth*` other two adapters are just not visible. It can't see TWO of those THREE identical adapters.

I also couldn't find them on DMESG.

Adapters by themselves work fine I also tried to plug the cable
and their LED's blinking (I also checked them on another machine and they work fine).

Please help me!

What can I do? How can I debug? I need at least one of them to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see them with `dmesg`?  You've got a problem.  Do they show up with `lspci`?  You'll probably notice matching PCI bus messages (without a driver loaded) matching the `lspci` info.  `lspvi -v` will give even more detail, where you'll probably find that the chipsets and or IDs vary.

The commodity hardware market is such that everything is under constant revision and the manufacturers feel free to change interfaces without notice — because, after all, they provide driver disks.

Comment: lspci | grep "Ethernet" is showing me only those visible three optinos Oo

Comment: What kind of options do I have?

Comment: You need to look at the full `lspci` to find the unrecognized cards.  `lspci -v` will let you discern the differences between the PCI-Express x4 that works and the two that don't work.